# List<KeyValuePair<string, dynamic>> serialization

Tags: c#, .net, orleans

When I try to serialize the instance of class (which has `List<KeyValuePair<string, dynamic>>`). I get error:

> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Unsupported type
>   'System.String' encountered. Perhaps you need to mark it
>   [Serializable] or define a custom serializer for it?

When I make that `List` as `[NonSerialized]` all works okay.
What do you think about it. How can I fix it? I think this error because i have dynamic type.

Comment: It would help a lot if you could provide your code of the data and the class to serialize into.

Comment: Did you consider using a `Dictionary<string, dynamic>` instead of a  `List<KeyValuePair<string, dynamic>>`?

Comment: We certainly need to see more of your code. I tried to reproduce this, but was unable. See my project here: https://gist.github.com/ReubenBond/81cc5df63bfb7b700289decd7a5576fc

Answer (score 1):

This works for me.
`Dictionary<string, dynamic> kvp = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>();`
Not sure why you would use a `List<KeyValuePair>` anyways.

Comment: This is not exactly an answer to the question so it should be posted as a comment.

Comment: @RuiJarimba maybe the solution is to change the type from List<KeyValuePair> to Dictionary. Maybe the actual phrasing should be redacted a bit.

Comment: Both should work. List<KeyValuePair<string, dynamic>> works for me.